# Select multiple categories with is_tax

Tags: wp-query, woocommerce-offtopic, tax-query

i have a good function for exclude out of stock products from category. The problem is i want exclude for more than one category (really i want show only in one category, but i think this is the way. If someones know how show only in one category...). Here is the code. thanks!

```
/* Hyde out of stock product specific category */

add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'hide_out_of_stock_from_cat' );
function hide_out_of_stock_from_cat( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_tax( 'product_cat', 15 ) && $query->is_main_query() )     {
    $query->set( 'meta_query', array(array(
            'key'       => '_stock_status',
         'value'     => 'outofstock',
         'compare'   => 'NOT IN'
    )));
    }
}
```

Comment: Just provide an array of category IDs: e.g. `$query->is_tax( 'product_cat', [ 15, 16, 17 ] )` - 15, 16 and 17 are the IDs.. See [`is_tax()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_tax/).

Comment: @SallyCJ thanks, but if i use that code give me an error... I change [] with () but don't work

Comment: What error? Did you try `array( 15, 16, 17 )` ?

Comment: @SallyCJ works perfect. If you put answer i check like Valid

/* Hyde out of stock product specific category */

add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'hide_out_of_stock_from_cat' );
function hide_out_of_stock_from_cat( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_tax( 'product_cat', array( 15, 16, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 59, 60, 62, 63, 66 ) ) && $query->is_main_query() ) {
 $query->set( 'meta_query', array(array(
      'key'       => '_stock_status',
      'value'     => 'outofstock',
      'compare'   => 'NOT IN'
 )));
    }
}

Comment: I'm glad it helped you, Vektor. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @SallyCJ for the correct answer — you can supply an *array of category IDs/slugs/names* to [`is_tax()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_tax/) to check for multiple categories. Here is the correct code:

```
 /* Hyde out of stock product specific category */

 add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'hide_out_of_stock_from_cat' );
 function hide_out_of_stock_from_cat( $query ) {
     if ( $query->is_tax( 'product_cat', array( 15, 16, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 59, 60, 62, 63, 66 ) ) && $query->is_main_query() ) {
    $query->set( 'meta_query', array(array(
            'key'       => '_stock_status',
             'value'     => 'outofstock',
             'compare'   => 'NOT IN'
    )));
     }
 }
```